# How to apply color transform but leave the drop shadow in the same color

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a bitmap in as3. I want to tint the color of the bitmap, but also I want to have black drop shadow all the time.

How to achieve this?

```
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Assets.bitmap();

var dropShadow = new DropShadowFilter();
bitmap.filters = new Array(dropShadow);


var colorTransform = new ColorTransform();
colorTransform.color = 0xFF00FF;
bitmap.tranform.colorTransform = colorTransform;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with nesting. 
Create a `Sprite`, add the bitmap as a child of that sprite, then add the drop shadow to the sprite and the color transform to the bitmap (as before).

```
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Assets.bitmap();

var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
container.addChild(bitmap);

var dropShadow = new DropShadowFilter();
container.filters = new Array(dropShadow);

var colorTransform = new ColorTransform();
colorTransform.color = 0xFF00FF;
bitmap.tranform.colorTransform = colorTransform;

addChild(container); //wherever you were adding the bitmap, add the container instead.
```